# Does restoring a backup to your iphone overwrite all data on the phone?

Tags: iphone, backup

I got a new iphone and wasn't ready to transfer data from the old one yet (lots of photos I wanted to get off it), so I began using the new phone - taking pics etc. When I got ready to transfer the info off of the old phone, I backed it up and then restored the new phone to backup. My question is - is all the data that was on the new phone (none of it backed up to icloud or itunes of course) overwritten and therefore completely irretrievable even by a data recovery program? That's my assumption. Just confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When an iOS device is restored from a backup, everything that was on the device before the restore is removed from the device.

Comment: But if your pictures, contacts, calendar, notes, reminders, keychain and iCloud-drive are synced in iCloud, it will resync after you've restored the local backup.